# What is meant by the quantum integrity in a superconducting loop

Tags: experimental-physics, superconductivity

I encountered this in the context of using squid microscopy to test for d-wave pairing in an iron arsenide superconductor where the goal of the experiment was to detect half integer flux quantum transitions to indirectly observe a change in the order parameter.

Comment: Which reference did you use?

Comment: Integer and half-integer flux-quantum transitions in a niobium–iron pnictide loop by Chen et al. Nat Phys 6